# How do I run Google Dataprep jobs automatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

Is there a way to trigger Google Dataprep flow over API?

I need to run like 30 different flows every day. Every day the source dataset changes and the result has to be appended to Google BigQuery table. Is there a way to automate this process? Source files are .xls files. I can upload them to cloud storage and write a cloud function that will upload it wherever Dataprep needs. The problem is that it seems to be impossible to replace the source dataset in a Dataprep flow. If so, then what's the point of scheduled runs and the new Job Run API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You will probably end up combining the [parameterization](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Overview-of-Operationalization_151992519) and the [scheduling](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Overview-of-Automator_118228674) features to run scheduled jobs that would pick new files every time.

Depending on your use case, you can for e.g. do:

#### Importing a directory

If you setup a directory that only contains one excel file (see picture below), you can use the [**+** button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546097/can-google-cloud-dataprep-monitor-a-gcs-path-for-new-files?rq=1) to use the directory as input dataset.
Every time you will run a job the files present in that directory will be processed.

[image: Import directory]

You can now schedule the job, create an output destination and you should be all set.

#### Using date time parameters

Let's assume you are in the situation where you add a new file every day with the date in the file name. For e.g. in Cloud storage, it would look like this:

[image: GCS UI]

You can use the **Parameterize** button in the Dataprep file browser and setup the following parameter:

[image: date time parameter]

This should select the file from the previous day:

[image: Preview of parameterization]

You can them import the dataset and schedule the flow. If your schedule run every day, it will pick up the new file each time.

#### Using variables

Alternatively, you can define a variable in the file path of your dataset.

[image: variable for the folder name]

You can then use the JobGroup API to override that variable.

```
POST /v4/jobGroups

{
  "wrangledDataset": {
    "id": datasetId
  },
  "runParameters": {
    "overrides": {
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "folder-name",
          "value": "new folder name"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note that for this to work, your file need to have the same structure. See https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Create-Dataset-with-Parameters_118228628#structuring-your-data for more details.

Using a wildcard parameter should also be possible as an alternative to the first method should also be possible.

Comment: Docs say overrides are unavailable: "Applying runtime overrides to jobs through the APIs is not supported in your product" https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/API-JobGroups-Create-v4_145281446

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two different things.

How to trigger jobs via API: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/API-JobGroups-Create-v4_145281446

How to effectively replace datasets dynamically:    https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Overview-of-Parameterization_118228665